# what is the equivalent in Javascript of this Python code?

Tags: javascript, python

Here is a python code, I want to translate it to javascript, any help?

```
result = list()
...
if not string in result:
   result.append(string)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check out [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), [`.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [`.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Comment: Also, in python, it reads slightly nicer if you do `if string not in result` :-)

Comment: I don't know about javascript, but in Python you can ensure that only unique values are in your collection by using a set instead of a list. `result = set(strings)` is a lot easier than `for string in strings: if string not in result: result.append(string))`

Comment: Jusnt In case...

    result = [];
    if(result.indexOf(string) > -1 ){
      result.push(string);
    }